# Have to refresh page for ajax request, page_html method deprecated issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to generate and redirect ajaxs request from forms and display messages as soon they`re created. I've been able to get it to work, but unfortunately I have to refresh the page for the message to show up.

The problem is that I'm currently using rails 4.1.7 and the replace_html method is deprecated, the latest stable version being v3.0.9

```
# messages controller
before_action :set_message, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
respond_to :html, :json

def index
  @messages = Message.all
  @the_message = Message.new
  respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
      render :update do |page|
        page.replace_html 'messages', :partial => 'list', :locals => {:messages => @messages}
      end
}
  format.html
  end
end

 def create
   @the_message = Message.new(message_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @the_message.save
       format.json { redirect_to messages_path(:format => :json) }
       format.html { redirect_to messages_path }
     else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @the_message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

In the form partial, I'm setting remote to true so rails will convert the HTML form into one that can send ajax requests. And I`m setting the format option to json so the server can send javascript back to automatically update the message list.

```
<%= form_for(@the_message, :remote=>true, :format => json) do |f| %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

Then I created a partial that only generates the part of the page with the message-list, and rendered it in the index file

```
#_list.html.erb
<% messages.each do |message| %>
    ...
<% end %>

#index.html.erb
<%= render 'list', :messages => @messages %>
```

How can I fix this? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was able to solve the problem.

I removed all this from the index method:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json {
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html 'messages', :partial => 'list', :locals => {:messages => @messages}
    end
  }
   format.html
end
```

And then I created a create.js.erb file, identical to the list.html.erb file, but replacing:

```
<% messages.each do |message| %>
  <%= message.stuff %>
  <%= message.moreStuff %>
  etc..
<% end %>
```

with:

```
<%= @the_message.stuff %>
<%= @the_message.moreStuff %>
etc..
```